# ¿Cómo puedo leer un campo específico dentro de un objeto JSON que se encuentra en "X" index de un array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

Tengo un código donde guardo X objeto JSON con determinados valores de unos input de un formulario dentro de un array. El objeto que guardo es este:

```
var arrayProductoInd = {
            "nombre" : nombre,
            "desc" : desc,
            "cant" : cant,
            "track": track,
            "checkMed" : checkMed,
            "ancho" : ancho,
            "largo" : largo,
            "alto" : alto,
            "checkPeso" : checkPeso,
            "peso" : peso
        };
```

Y la manera en la que lo guardo dentro del array llamado "arrayProductoInd", es ésta:

```
arrayProductos.push(arrayProductoInd);
```

Ahora, cuando trato de hacer un html() dentro de un contenedor donde se va a mostrar solo el nombre guardado dentro de cada uno de los objetos existentes dentro del array, me aparece en la consola que arrayProductoInd no está definido. Sin embargo cuando tomo la longitud de dicho array dentro del "for" que voy a mostrar a continuación, sí lo detecta:

```
$(".productos").html("");

    var contenido = "";

    var k = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayProductos.length; i++) {

        k++;

        contenido += '<article class="productos producto' + k + '"><h1>' + arrayProductos[i][0] + '</h1><input type="hidden" value="' + i + '"/></article>';
    }

    $(".productos").html(contenido);
```

No logro entender el porqué de este error. Traté colocando "**arrayProductos[i].nombre**" también, pero no logré un resultado satisfactorio.

Comment: `arrayProductos[i].nombre` parece correcto. Pareciera en la pregunta que estás confundiendo las variables `arrayProductos` y `arrayProductosInd`. Faltaría ver un ejemplo que contenga todo.

Comment: En el FOR ya no utilizo el arrayProductosInd directamente. Sino que solo utilizo el array "contenedor" para acceder al más pequeño. Que en sí, es un objeto Json.

Comment: Puede ser cualquier cosa. Lo que nos estás mostrando son pedazos de código suelto. Creo que para poder ayudarte sería bueno saber cómo se conectan, en qué archivo o sección (y en qué orden) está cada parte. Cuándo se ejecutan, etc...

Comment: La variable `k` no es necesaria, en donde la usabas se puede poner `... producto' + (i+1) + '"...` (los paréntesis son importantes para que se haga primero y sume como números en vez de como texto)

Comment: No puedo reproducir el error que mencionas. Por favor, crea un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) donde muestres el error que te encuentras. He copiado [tu código a JSFiddle y funciona perfectamente](https://jsfiddle.net/bphmsqpq/) con `arrayProductos[i].nombre`.

Comment: La variable K SI es necesaria. La utilizo para crear nombres de class secundarios para luego llamarlos con el metodo split en jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema estaba en que la forma correcta de acceder un objeto que se encuentra dentro un específico index de un array es la siguiente:

```
array[x]["atributo"]
```

En mi caso, para acceder al nombre del producto que estaba guardado, solo necesitaba hacer lo siguiente dentro del "for":

```
arrayProductos[i]["nombre"]
```

De todas maneras, gracias por su tiempo y ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

En tu ejemplo arrayProductoInd  podria considerarse un objeto, entonces podrias usar JsonParser para obtener el valor de los campos:

usando jquery:

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(arrayProductoInd);
var nombre = obj['nombre'];
```

Javascript:

```
var obj = JSON.parse( arrayProductoInd);
var nombre = obj['nombre'];
```

Comment: No me sirvió el parse json. No se cual podrá ser el problema

Comment: Hola Criss usas arrayProductoInd? no arrarProductos!

Comment: Hola Elena! Lo probé así también pero no funcionó. No se cual será el error.

Answer (score 0):

la creacion del objeto json esta mal, deberias ser asi:

```
var arrayProductoInd = {
        nombre:"nombre",
        desc:"desc",
        cant:"cant",
        track:"track",
        checkMed:"checkMed",
        ancho:"ancho",
        largo:"largo",
        alto:"alto",
        checkPeso:"checkPeso",
        peso:"peso"
    };
```

y para recorrer dicho objeto, lo puedes hacer asi:

```
for (var key in arrayProductoInd) {
   console.log(' name=' + key + ' value=' + arrayProductoInd[key]);
}
```

Saludos

Comment: Ya ha surgido la misma confusión en una pregunta que hice en el pasado. No está mal formulado el objeto JSON. Esto se debe a que el atributo es simplemente un nombre y el valor es una variable que está pre-definida en el código unos pasos atrás. Un objeto JSON puede contener elementos los cuales sean: 1)Ambos strings 2)El atributo es string y el valor es una variable. De todos modos, el problema ya está solucionado. Lo aclaré respondiendo a mi propia pregunta más abajo. Gracias por tu tiempo de todos modos.

Answer (score -1):

El problema está en la definición del for.

El primer elemento de un array en javascript tiene índice 0, por lo que si el array tiene, por ejemplo, 4 elementos arrayProductos.length será 4 pero los índices definidos en el array serán de 0 a 3.

Tú estas haciendo el bucle de 0 a 4 por lo que el índice 4 te da un error porque no existe.

Por otro lado la variable k toma los mismos valores que i por lo que podrías prescindir de ella.

```
    $(".productos").html("");
        var contenido = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayProductos.length - 1; i++) {
            contenido += '<article class="productos producto' + i + '"><h1>' + arrayProductos[i][0] + '</h1><input type="hidden" value="' + i + '"/></article>';
        }
        $(".productos").html(contenido);
```

Fíjate que defino el array desde 0 hasta arrayProductos.length -1.

Comment: Esta respuesta es incorrecta. El bucle `for` del código de la pregunta va desde 0 hasta `arrayProductos.length - 1` porque se usa el comparador `<` y  no `<=`; además el bucle de esta respuesta hace una iteración de menos por eso mismo. Por ejemplo, si `arrayProductos.length` es 4, el bucle de esta respuesta hace 0, 1, 2 (y  no llega a 3, dejando un elemento fuera del bucle)

Comment: Cierto. Se ve que estaba todavía medio dormido.

Answer (score -1):

el JSON:

```
{
    "user": {
        "_id": "asdfa43535534534534",
        "name": "mi nombre",
        "rut": "sadfasdfasdf",
        "email": "correo@gmail.com",
        "role": "cat1",
        "phone": 1234555555,
        "account_type": "cta_corriente",
        "bank": "mi banco",
        "bank_account": 123,
        "date": "2020-03-26T20:32:21.137Z",
        "status": "active",
        "password": "$sdfasdfasdfasdfasd.",
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

para mostrar el nombre:

```
<h5 className="card-title">{items['user'].name}</h5>
```

Comment: Es una respuesta?

Comment: Si esto es una respuesta te sugerimos a portar más información,revisa por favor [answer] y editala, saludos.