# Imprimir parte especifica de un json con php

Tags: php, json

Quiero imprimir solo los valores "results"

```
{
    "seller_id": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "query": null,
    "paging": {
        "limit": 50,
        "offset": 0,
        "total": 1
    },
    "results": [
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ],
    "filters": [],
    "available_filters": [
        {
            "id": "status",
            "name": "Status",
            "values": [
                {
                    "id": "pending",
                    "name": "Inactive items for debt or MercadoLibre policy violation",
                    "results": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": "not_yet_active",
                    "name": "Items newly created or pending activation",
                    "results": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": "programmed",
                    "name": "Items scheduled for future activation",
                    "results": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": "active",
                    "name": "Active items",
                    "results": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": "paused",
                    "name": "Paused Items",
                    "results": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": "closed",
                    "name": "Closed Items",
                    "results": 0
                }
            ]
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo?

Comment: Buenas Samuel, si hubieras buscado un poquito en google, te hubieran salido muchos resultados, y varios de ellos en esta misma pagina. Posiblemente, esta respuesta solucione tu problema. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/9478/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-leer-un-campo-espec%C3%ADfico-dentro-de-un-objeto-json-que-se-encuentra-e

Comment: si busque antes, la verdad no fui mas especifico por que en una anterior consulta me indicaron ir al punto y editaron mi pregunta , lo intente con forech pero no he podido llegar a imprimir exactamente lo que necesito

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione de la siguiente manera.

en este caso especifico solo quería imprimir "results" que estan dentro de "values" que a su vez esta dentro de "available_filters"

utilice json decode de la siguiente forma:

require 'php-json-file-decode-master/json-file-decode.class.php';

$read = new json_file_decode();

$json = $read->json("https:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

print_r($json["available_filters"][0]["values"][4]["results"])

el resultado es 1